# Uploaded images not displaying

Tags: php

I am running a php code for multiple image upload and its working fine on my WAMP local server and the images displays when echoed out:

```
<?php

if(is_array($_FILES))   
 {  
      foreach ($_FILES['files']['name'] as $name => $value)  
      {  
           $file_name = explode(".", $_FILES['files']['name'][$name]);  
           $allowed_ext = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif");  
           if(in_array($file_name[1], $allowed_ext))  
           {  
                $new_name = substr(sha1(mt_rand()),0,50) . '.' . $file_name[1];  
                $sourcePath = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$name];  
                $target = "photos/".$new_name;  
                if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath, $target))  
                {  
                     echo "<img src='".$target."' />";
                }                 
           }            
      }   
 }  

?>
```

But when I uploaded it to my website, the images are being uploaded to the photos folder but the images doesn't echo out.

This is a screenshot of my WAMP local server:
[image: This is a screenshot of my WAMP local server:]

And here is for my website:
[image: And here is for my website]

Comment: It usually boils down to => http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Use firebug to check the path that it's currently holding.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know what is firebug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out my mistake, the code above doesn't correspond with my website code I don't know how but I had a slight error like this

```
$allowed_ext = array("jpg". "jpeg", "png", "gif");
```

And I am uploading it through the `jQuery` `$.ajax` so I can't get any error directly from my php page